# Is it possible to display a gif and music in as part of conditional/response to prompt on python?

Tags: javascript, python, conditional-statements

I am running Jupyter Notebook and my goal is to display a gif and to play a song at the same time (both local files)...

This is my in-progress code:

```
poll = input("Display music and picture? ")

if poll.lower() == "yes":

    from IPython.display import Image
    Image("you.gif") 

    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["afplay", "dubstep.m4a"])

else:
    print ("Duly Noted")
```

In response to inputted "Yes" the music plays, but no images displays. I tried just the image import on another line and it opened fine. Is it possible to run both the image and the music in response to my conditional?

Also, how would I have a few images flash up for 3 seconds at a time and then disappear?

Thanks,
   Jon Doe

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work as you are expecting because of precedence:

```
if poll == "yes" or "YES" or "Yes":
```

What will work is:

```
if poll in ("yes", "YES", "Yes"):
```

or better yet:

```
if poll.lower() == "yes":
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill test that out!

Comment: That was definitely very helpful with the syntax of my code; however, still not luck on getting the image to appear.